# War Boy / Mad Max 3 connection?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road, mad-max-3

In *Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome* when Max gets sent into the desert and finds the kids from the plane crash there's this one kid that's always to himself and paints his face very pale.

In the following movie *Mad Max: Fury Road*, the War Boys have a very similar look. Max also forms an emotional bond with one of the War Boys.

Is there possibly a connection between the two characters?

Is there anything definitive from the makers?

Comment: See - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90481/is-scrooloose-from-beyond-thunderdome-a-stranded-war-boy

Comment: Not sure that he necessarily formed an "emotional bond" with the war boy. Not until the war boy pretty much denounced his ways and made personal sacrifice to help them in their cause.  Even then, that bond wasn't especially personal or strong, that I can remember. The war boy thought they were buds from the start, but I didn't see that from Max.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet yeah I just didn't know any other words to describe it...

Comment: I do know that the producers said that this story does not necessarily share the history/continuity with the others, necessarily.  I think most involved want to pretend that Thunderdome never happened, as well.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Paulie_D's link is pretty useful

Comment: Seeing as it's Immortan Joe's cult and Joe is older than Max, I don't see how that could be.

Comment: @sirjonsnow that's why I think it's weird...